# How many troops did the Confederate and Union army have in each year of the Civil War?

Tags: american-civil-war

How many troops did each army of the civil war have in each year of the war from 1861-1864 and how many casualties did they have each year?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Answer (score 4):

As I remember, at the beginning of 1861 there were about 16,000 soldiers in the United States Army, the regular army, and the United States Volunteers were not yet formed.

And at the beginning of 1861 the Confederate States of American was not yet formed and didn't have any armed forces.

By January 1865 the Confederate army had already some time earlier reached its maximum size and had been declining rapidly in numbers for some time, probably having about 200,000 to 300,000 total men available for duty in January 1865.

The total number of Union soldiers reached about 1,000,000  in May 1865, when enlistment stopped and men started to be discharged.  At that time there were about 600,000 men available for duty out of the 1,000,000 enlisted.

I remember seeing a table  somewhere like you asked about, with the numbers of Union and Rebel soldiers for each year of the war, but I have not found it yet.

Added 03-09-2020:

Here is something:

> In July 1861, the two armies were nearly equal in strength with less than 200,000 soldiers on each side; however at the peak of troop strength in 1863, Union soldiers outnumbered Confederate soldiers by a ratio of 2 to 1. The size of Union forces in January 1863 totaled over 600,000. Two years later, that number had not changed dramatically for the Union Army but had dropped to about 200,000 for the Confederate Army.

https://www.nps.gov/civilwar/facts.htm[2](https://www.nps.gov/civilwar/facts.htm)

Here is a link to a chart with the size of the United States armed forces by branch each year from 1789 to 1997:

https://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Stats/US_Mil_Manpower_1789-1997.htm[1](https://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Stats/US_Mil_Manpower_1789-1997.htm)

Comment: Upon reconsideration, I suspect your original claim may be correct.  Although broken into pieces, the area of the C.S.A. isn't really beginning to lose population centres (except New Orleans) until early 1865.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens  I have rewritten my sentence to make my meaning clearer. "By January 1865 the Confederate army had already some time earlier reached its maximum size and had been declining rapidly in numbers for some time, probably having about 200,000 to 300,000 total men available for duty in January 1865."  I think that makes my meaning clearer.

Comment: That works for me.